# Database/-set containing information about rice yield and growth duration

Tags: data-request, research, agriculture, asia

I am looking for a database or -set that contains information about rice seed varieties in Asia. Ideally such a dataset would contain the following keys:

- growth duration
- mean yield
- rice variety
- location the data was obtained (e.g. country)

I know there scientific publications regarding the relationship between growth duration and yield (e.g. [Vergara et al. (1966)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00380768.1966.10431180), [Hussain et al. (2014)](http://www.thejaps.org.pk/docs/v-24-5/30.pdf)), however most of them are either outdated, incomplete or only relating to a small, specific area.

I am trying to correlate the information on growth duration and mean yield to another dataset containing information about growing season lengths and thus estimate the rice production volume.

Any accessible database, API or file format is fine. Regarding the license the dataset would need to be accessible for non-commercial, scientific use with the option to publish derived results.

Do you know any database or -set that contains this information and can be considered relatively "complete", i.e. current and large in size representing the most common rice varieties?